# Scheduled downloads in IOS using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can one do a scheduled download of data (json) in an app without using background fetch or a silent push notification? I have implemented a background fetch which performs the task at irregular intervals (based on app usage). User's wish to have the check done even if they are not regular users of the app.

Comment: classic XY-problem; your client should rather use some kinda metrics here (e.g. Adobe, Google, etc...) to measure such interactions / habits / behaviours.

Comment: Basically, the demand from the client is that they want regular, hourly downloads even if they have not used the app in a week. There is no compromise here as they believe the background fetch from Apple offers no value whatsoever.

Comment: consider the scenario e.g. the app is actually terminated and that is not going to be able to fetch anything in such state at all – regardless how many meetings or how much time the marketing guys have spend on deciding that they _want_ such feature, it might be better to calm them down in my view.